# parsing xml data with vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, xml-parsing

I am currently attempting to parse data with VB.net to populate some textboxes selecting by childname "eResponse.01", 02, 03 etc however a namespace / schema location in the main tag seems to be tripping up the code.

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\james\Desktop\NEMSIS\EMS\xml\Test.xml")
    Dim xmlns As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    xmlns.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www1w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    xmlns.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "http://www.nemsis.org http://nemsis.org/media/nemsis_v3/release-3.4.0/XSDs/NEMSIS_XSDs/EMSDataSet_v3.xsd")
    xmlns.AddNamespace("xmlns", "http://www.nemsis.org")
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/EMSDataSet/Header/PatientCareReport/eResponse")
    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        TextEdit1.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("eResponse.03").InnerText
    Next
```

works fine when using the following

```
<EMSDataSet>
<Header>
    <DemographicGroup>
        <dAgency.01>0</dAgency.01>
        <dAgency.02>00</dAgency.02>
        <dAgency.04>49</dAgency.04></DemographicGroup>
    <PatientCareReport>
        <eRecord>
            <eRecord.01>OpP</eRecord.01>
            <eRecord.SoftwareApplicationGroup>
                <eRecord.02>G</eRecord.02>
                <eRecord.03>Q</eRecord.03>
                <eRecord.04>P</eRecord.04></eRecord.SoftwareApplicationGroup></eRecord>
        <eResponse>
            <eResponse.AgencyGroup>
                <eResponse.01>a</eResponse.01>
                <eResponse.02>BL</eResponse.02></eResponse.AgencyGroup>
            <eResponse.03>u33</eResponse.03>
```

however it does not populate anything if I include the namespace/schema

```
<EMSDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nemsis.org http://nemsis.org/media/nemsis_v3/release-3.4.0/XSDs/NEMSIS_XSDs/EMSDataSet_v3.xsd" xmlns="http://www.nemsis.org">
<Header>
    <DemographicGroup>
        <dAgency.01>0</dAgency.01>
        <dAgency.02>00</dAgency.02>
        <dAgency.04>49</dAgency.04></DemographicGroup>
    <PatientCareReport>
        <eRecord>
            <eRecord.01>OpP</eRecord.01>
            <eRecord.SoftwareApplicationGroup>
                <eRecord.02>G</eRecord.02>
                <eRecord.03>Q</eRecord.03>
                <eRecord.04>P</eRecord.04></eRecord.SoftwareApplicationGroup></eRecord>
        <eResponse>
            <eResponse.AgencyGroup>
                <eResponse.01>a</eResponse.01>
                <eResponse.02>BL</eResponse.02></eResponse.AgencyGroup>
            <eResponse.03>u33</eResponse.03>
```

what do I need to do to get my code to ignore extra data in the opening tag - removing that information is not an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add namespace using xmlnamespacemanager in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275837/add-namespace-using-xmlnamespacemanager-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You need to use the `XmlNamespaceManager` - an example is linked in my duplicate comment.

Comment: I appologize I copied old code - I have already tried namespacemanager and either failed the syntax or dont understand it - edited to show what was used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has unprefixed namespace -also known as *default namespace*- here :

```
xmlns="http://www.nemsis.org"
```

unlike prefixed namespace, descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace *implicitly*.

To access elements in namespace, you need to use registered prefix properly in your XPath and pass the namespace manager as 2nd argument of `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` :

```
......
xmlns.AddNamespace("d", "http://www.nemsis.org")
Dim xpath As String = "/d:EMSDataSet/d:Header/d:PatientCareReport/d:eResponse"
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath, xmlns)
For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
    TextEdit1.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("d:eResponse.03", xmlns).InnerText
Next
```

Comment: I had attempted this earlier however received an error stating System.ArgumentException: Prefix "xmlns" is reserved for use by XML.
   at System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace(String prefix, String uri)
   at EPCR.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\FTDEPCR\EPCR\EPCR\Form1.vb:line 47

Comment: I didn't aware that `xmlns` is reserved, thought any prefix is fine as long as it points to the correct uri