# How to convert GML string to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have a GML string:

```
<gml:LineString><gml:coordinates>1537544.53,452064.2 1537541.719999999,452062.3099999999 1537523.159999999,452044.55 1537544.53,452064.2</gml:coordinates></gml:LineString>
```

Now i want to convert it to xml document

```
var t = "<gml:LineString>....</gml:LineString>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
doc.Load(t);
```

But on `doc.Load(t);` got exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: "Prefix "gml" undeclared."
```

How to add namespace and read read line?

**UPDATE**
I'd fix code based on @jdweng answer:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { NameTable = new NameTable() };
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(settings.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, "", XmlSpace.Default);

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(gmlString), settings, context);

 if (gmlString.StartsWith("<gml:Polygon>"))
 {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PolygonType));
     return new tGeoLPT { Item = (PolygonType)serializer.Deserialize(reader) 
   };
 }
```

Comment: @dlatikay Yeah, but i don't see how can i use it before `Load()`

Comment: I believe you'll need to use an `XmlReader` to read the string.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You mean `XmlReader.Create()`?

Comment: Sure. You could also use an `XmlTextReader`. The important part is passing in the `NameTable` setting. You might also want to take a look at [add namespace using xmlnamespacemanager in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6275837/215552), which has an answer using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string coordinates = "1537544.53,452064.2 1537541.719999999,452062.3099999999 1537523.159999999,452044.55 1537544.53,452064.2";
            string line = "<gml:LineString  xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\"></gml:LineString>";
            XElement xLine = XElement.Parse(line);
            XNamespace ns = xLine.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("gml");
            xLine.Add(new XElement(ns + "coordinates"), coordinates);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i got mistake in adding namespace.